# clothing required in Jungfrau tour in Oct 2016

Tags: switzerland, clothing, mountain-climbing, jungfrau-region

will be visiting switzerland / jungfrau in October 2016.  What dress precaution required for us there.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on high up you want to go. You can take the train up the Jungfraujoch. That's almost 3500 m of altitude and hence it's cold, even in Summer. Means: below freezing even in August. Check out http://www.jungfrau.ch/en/tourism/destinations/jungfraujoch-top-of-europe/weather/

Prepare for ice, snow, and significant sub-zero temperatures. The lower you stay the warmer it will be.

Comment: Not really a help for someone who likely has never seen zero C temperatures, even less sub-zero F which can be up there in October in bad weather.